# Error merging 2 point layers with same CRS

Tags: qgis, merge

I've edited 2 point layers with the Refactor Processing tool in QGIS 2.18.5 to re-order and edit the attribute fields so both layers will merge without creating additional fields in the merge. With both point layers saved with the same CRS, the merge tool gives me the error that 'All layers must have the same geometry type!'

I've also checked the field types match up (integer, string etc) which they do.
I've tried with the raw data, before changing the order of fields in the attribute table but still no luck. I currently have no issue merging other shapefiles.

An additional observation: I've noticed when my data goes out of the field of view within the map canvas, the icon in the layers panel changes from a single dot to 3 smaller, unfilled dots (the same icon when categorising the styling of point data).

Comment: Given they are both point layers, only cause I can think of is the difference between point and multipoint. Can you check the Metadata (Properties) to see if one of your layer is `Point (WKB type: "MultiPoint")` or something like it ?

Comment: nice one! One of them is a multipoint. I suppose it's a simple conversion to single point then?

Comment: I don't know how to convert multipoint to point. If you are ok to convert point to multipoint, it can be done when saving it as new shapefile. (1) Select the point layer (2) `Save As...` (3) Geometry type= `Point` and `Force multi-type`.

Comment: Just vector > geometry tools > multipart to singlepart. Thanks very much, you can answer the question if you wish!

Comment: Yes, that will do! Almost forgot that tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS `Merge vector layers` tool accepts only same geometry type as input. 
It even makes a point of distinguishing multi-type geometry from single one.